# Error 32: Running multiple Django sites using 'python manage.py runserver' in Gunicorn-Nginx

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

I have some Django sites running on a Nginx-Gunicorn server. But at some point I am getting Broken Pipe errors as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/root/djangoapps/env/mmiradio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 143, in _init_
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in _init_
self.finish()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
self.wfile.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
 self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
```

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I have 'python manage.py runserver' in my gunicorn config for each site, so doubts whether that causes the problem ? As official Django says NEVER use it on production server.

Comment: if you have nginx and gunicorn set up why using runserver on top of that ?

Comment: I had just used a gunicorn_config.py file which can be run like /path-to-env/python /path-to-env/bin/gunicorn -c /path-to-project/gunicorn_config.py project.wsgi in nginx terminal , Is that causing this error and makes site horribly slow ?

Comment: frankly i have no idea, i never actually explicitly used anything .wsgi, but using gunicorn+nginx AND runserver definitely doesn't sound good

Answer (score 0):

You are running two servers.  See here:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port
```

The runserver command is just a convenient little server for use in development.